# particles.js restart or run multiple instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery, particles.js

Can anyone figure out how to run this function multiple times or restart it somehow? Because it only to seems to run once before throwing an error that "pJS is not a function" when I try to use it again. And also what would be the most efficient way of going about it?
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

EXAMPLE: https://jsfiddle.net/MatrX/rfd7es3y/

```js
/* ---------- particles.js SETTINGS ------------ */
    function particles_bg(id){
        pJS(id, {
          "particles": {
            "number": {
              "value": 1500,
              "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 700
              }
            },
            "color": {
              "value": "#ffffff"
            },
            "shape": {
              "type": "circle",
              "stroke": {
                "width": 0,
                "color": "#000000"
              },
              "polygon": {
                "nb_sides": 5
              },
              "image": {
                "src": "img/github.svg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 100
              }
            },
            "opacity": {
              "value": 0.5,
              "random": false,
              "anim": {
                "enable": true,
                "speed": 0.2,
                "opacity_min": 0,
                "sync": false
              }
            },
            "size": {
              "value": 2,
              "random": true,
              "anim": {
                "enable": true,
                "speed": 2,
                "size_min": 0,
                "sync": false
              }
            },
            "line_linked": {
              "enable": false,
              "distance": 150,
              "color": "#ffffff",
              "opacity": 0.4,
              "width": 1
            },
            "move": {
              "enable": true,
              "speed": 0.2,
              "direction": "none",
              "random": true,
              "straight": false,
              "out_mode": "out",
              "bounce": false,
              "attract": {
                "enable": false,
                "rotateX": 600,
                "rotateY": 1200
              }
            }
          },
          "interactivity": {
            "detect_on": "canvas",
            "events": {
              "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "bubble"
              },
              "onclick": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "push"
              },
              "resize": true
            },
            "modes": {
              "grab": {
                "distance": 400,
                "line_linked": {
                  "opacity": 1
                }
              },
              "bubble": {
                "distance": 85,
                "size": 1,
                "duration": 3,
                "opacity": 1,
                "speed": 3
              },
              "repulse": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4
              },
              "push": {
                "particles_nb": 4
              },
              "remove": {
                "particles_nb": 2
              }
            }
          },
          "retina_detect": true
        });
        //document.getElementById("pJS").remove();

    }
/* ---------- particles.js RUN ------------ */
particles_bg('p1');
particles_bg('p2');
```

Comment: Seems like you have two `var pJS`... On line `1` and `127` of the Fiddle code.

Comment: hmm... that is interesting... but those particular statements are none of which I wrote... looks like it came like this from github. That's why I'm having a bit difficulties figuring this script out.